# True or false, if $A^2 = \mathbb{I}$ and $B^2 = \mathbb{I}$, then $(AB)^{-1} = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The title says it all, is $A^2 = \mathbb{I}$ and $B^2 = \mathbb{I}$, then $(AB)^{-1} = BA$ valid or not. The question is more per say on how I would solve this question (rather than just being spoon fed)

I have no idea how I should tackle this problem.

Comment: Show that $det(AB) \neq 0$. What you are asked to prove is $(BA)(AB)=\mathbb I$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with,
$$A^2 = \mathbb{I}$$
$$A\cdot{A} = \mathbb{I}$$
$$A\cdot\mathbb{I}\cdot{A} = \mathbb{I}$$
$$A\cdot{B^2}\cdot{A} = \mathbb{I}$$
$$(AB)\cdot{BA} = \mathbb{I}  $$
$$ BA = (AB)^{-1}$$

This is assuming, $AB$ is invertible i.e. $|AB|\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

$A^{-1}$ is a matrix for such $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = \mathbb{I}$. That's the definition of inverse matrix. If you are given that $A^2=\mathbb{I}$, you can also write it as $AA=\mathbb{I}$ From here, you see that $A=A^{-1}$. The same holds for $B$.

You can also figure out what is $(AB)^{-1}$ from this definition.$$
(AB)(AB)^{-1} = \mathbb{I}\\
ABB^{-1}A^{-1} = A\mathbb{I}A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=\mathbb{I}
$$
making these equal:$$
(AB)(AB)^{-1} = (AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})
$$
And you get that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$. And we know that $A=A^{-1}$ and $B=B^{-1}$, so we know that $B^{-1}A^{-1} = BA$. And you're done.